# Is it possible to embed Facebook reel videos on a website?

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, embed

How to embed Facebook reels in website?

Embed option only visible on Facebook Video public posts. But on Facebook reel video can't find an option for embed. I want to embed it using iframe for facebook reels in my website. Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I don't think Facebook currently provides any way to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I noticed they blocked that feature as well, but I found out from the FB developers page that you can just embed it like a post with the same dimensions as your video:
**- You need to use their code generator from here:**

Link to documentation and **code generator:**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts